# Attacking AES-128 with Grover's algorithm

Tags: aes, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, grovers-algorithm

How many plain text / cipher text pairs are required by Grover's algorithm when it is used to try and discover a secret AES key?

I am trying to determine if having a device which limits the speed at which it produces cipher texts from plain texts will help protect against this attack.

Comment: If you want to foil Grover's, just use 256 bit AES keys

Comment: @poncho due to  $\sqrt{}$ ?

Comment: @kelalaka Correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) is a brute-force quantum algorithm with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ with asymptotically optimal on unstructured data. There is also "Quantum Computing and Hidden Variables" in  $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt[3]{N})$ by [Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/qchvpra.pdf).

**Ensuring uniqueness of the solution**

Requires ECB mode;

Let $n$ denotes the block size.

Let $r$ be the number of different plaintext-ciphertext pairs.

Let $r$ denotes the number of the simultaneous plaintext-ciphertext pairs  encrypted under two secret keys $k_1 \neq k_2$.

Then the expected result of having a different result if the $r$ plaintext are different;

$$ 1- \frac{1}{2^{rn}}$$

A good estimate on $r$ is given as;

$$r > \lceil 2^k/n \rceil$$

**For AES-128**

$n=128, k=128 \Rightarrow r=3$

**For AES-192**

$n=128, k=192 \Rightarrow r=4$

**For AES-256**

$n=128, k=256 \Rightarrow r=5$

for more details, see *"Applying Grover’s algorithm to AES:
quantum resource estimates"*  [at #3.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04965.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Grover's algorithm has search complexity $\sqrt{2^{128}}$ for AES 128. In plain ECB mode, one plaintext/ciphertext pair will be enough since the cipher mapping is a permutation.

Interestingly very recently a combination of Grover's algorithm and Simon's algorithm have been used to:

> Convert the classical advanced slide attacks (introduced by Biryukov and Wagner) to a quantum one, that gains an exponential speed-up of the time complexity.

The authors of the [quoted paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/504.pdf) include Xiaoyun Wang who came up with the best attacks on MD5 and earlier versions of SHA.

Specifically, they extend quantum slide attacks to Feistel Ciphers.

**Edit:**

For an $n$ bit block cipher with $n$ bit keys the original slide attack has $O(2^{n/2})$ complexity and requires as many plaintext/ciphertext pairs.

The [attakcs by Kaplan et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05973.pdf) cited in the above paper require $O(n)$ complexity but those need to be modified for Feistel ciphers according to the paper quoted above.

Comment: "one plaintext/ciphertext pair will be enough since the cipher mapping is a permutation" There will be many permutations that have the same mapping, right? This part is the only part of the post that is actually answering the question, or am I mistaken?